# Does redux have a built in delete method to alter hash values of an application's state?I

Tags: javascript, redux

I came across this piece of code (I'll just post the snippet that I have a question about), which removes a todo item from a hash (the hash of todo items is the application's state). Essentially, the removed todo item should not show up in future versions of this application's state.

```
case REMOVE_TODO:
      nextState = Object.assign({}, state);
      delete nextState[action.todo.id];
      return nextState;
```

I understand that a different way to approach this problem would be to use the `.filter` method to get the correct hash elements; but what is this built in `delete` method/piece of code doing? I can't seem to find any official documentation of this anywhere; resource links or answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is a JavaScript built-in operator that *"removes a property from an object"* (see the [documentation from the Mozilla community](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).

Re:

> I understand that a different way to approach this problem would be to use the filter method to get the correct hash elements

You'd use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for an array, but your example chose to keep the TODOs in an object where each TODO is a value of a different property of that object<sup>(1)</sup>, hence the need for 'property removal'.

---

(1) It's a usage of an object as a ["map" data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) - see some thoughts on such practice in [the documentation for the dedicated `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) introduced into JavaScript later. In general, maps are used because they help to get to a value by id faster than from a list data-structure like an array, which is because maps contain indexes that speed up searches by the key. Here in Redux though, this approach is especially common practice because [Redux recommends](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state/#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state) that *"each object should be stored once, keyed by ID, and other objects that reference it should only store the ID rather than a copy of the entire object"*.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for the doc link!! And I see, that makes sense, thanks :D